# How to run a simple ruby script in any web server (Apache or Mongrel or any thing else)

Tags: ruby, webserver

It seems very funny to me that when I search something related ruby, all ruby on rails related results popped up. So nobody using raw ruby anymore?

However, I am new to ruby. This morning I was only trying to run a simple hello world ruby script in web server, firstly apache 2 and then tried the mongrel. But unfortunately I failed. I googled every way I can, but result only shows regarding ruby on rails. So really is there any way to run a ruby script in any web server, or I have to use ror even if I just want to do a hello world application?

Comment: You sound like you are coming to Ruby from php or similar. The difference with Ruby is not that big, we just have a wide range of available frameworks to output the raw html code so we never write things like: puts "<html>".

Comment: Take a look at Ruby's [CGI](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/cgi/1.9.2/frames) library. It provides helpers for accessing the parameters, cookies and such. Creating CGI scripts, even without the library is simple once you understand how the CGI spec works.

Comment: Can you post your simple "hello world" example script? It would help to know what you are trying to do. Is it a script that renders HTML that should be displayed in a browser? Or a script that could be run from the command line?

Answer (score 10):

Sinatra is probably your best bet for getting a Ruby script running from a web server without Rails.

Take a look here: http://www.sinatrarb.com

From the Sinatra docs:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

Then, just run:

```
$ gem install sinatra
$ ruby -rubygems hi.rb
== Sinatra has taken the stage ...
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567
```

Just go to http://0.0.0.0:4567 in your browser and you should find your "Hello World"

...

To add on to this, since you also ask about running in Apache or other web servers, you may want to check out these tutorials about deploying your new Sinatra-based application to Apache or Nginx:

Apache: http://www.pastbedti.me/2009/11/deploying-a-sinatra-app-with-apache-and-phusion-passenger-a-k-a-mod_rack/ and http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=1716

Nginx: http://tommy.chheng.com/2009/06/09/deploying-a-sinatra-app-on-nginx-passenger-with-capistrano-and-git/

Note both tutorials cover running Sinatra via Passenger (http://www.modrails.com/ -- don't be put off by the "modrails" name :) ), which I have had good luck with in deploying apps under Apache and Nginx.

Comment: the links for apache was outdated... please update it

Answer (score 7):

You could configure Apache (for example) to run .rb files as CGI scripts, and then add a shebang line (`#!/path/to/your/ruby` or maybe `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`) at the top of the script.  It's not optimal, though, as it'd start a new interpreter for each request.

Comment: This is the traditional CGI and is fine for occasional use. Ruby's [CGI](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/cgi/1.9.2/frames) library is designed to help for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

The more commonly used way of running a ruby website is passenger: http://www.modrails.com/
It is not really hard to install and you use, here is he doc for apache: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_ruby_on_rails_application

Your application must be a valid rack application, here is a minimal hello world (let's say /app is your application's root folder):

/app/config.ru

```
require 'rack'
require 'app'
run(app)
```

/app/app.rb

```
app = proc do |env|
  [
    # http status code
    200,
    # headers
    {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'},
    # html body
    ["<head><title>Test Page</title></head><body>Hello World !</body>"]
  ]
end
```

Save the files above and create a subfolder /app/public (required by passenger to detect a ruby/rails/sinatra application) and use /app/public as DocumentRoot in your apache config.

This may look scary but this is for production deployment, in development your really don't want to mess with a real server.

All you need to run the config.ru file I gave above is:

```
$ gem install rack
$ rackup config.ru
```

Or if you want to be closer to your production system:

```
$ gem install passenger
$ cd /app
$ passenger start
```

which will install you an nginx server with passenger and run your application.

In most case you will never use rack directly but instead use ruby on rails, sinatra or another framework to generate the html for you (they all use rack below now to provide a common api with the webservers).

Comment: it's way too high of a set up, especially, newbies like us. I still don't know how to get this up and running.

Comment: I run "passenger start" and after reading "Downloading Nginx..." I almost pissed my pants. Now I have webrack, nginx AND Apache. Nice. :D

Answer (score 3):

Ruby 1.9.2+ simple command.

```
ruby -run -e httpd . -p 5000
```

from this article http://til.justincampbell.me/start-an-http-server-with-ruby-run/
other article https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255

Comment: I'm not a downvotey person, but this won't actually execute your script, just serve it as text.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard mod_ruby is good. Unlike, `#!/path/to/your/ruby`, mod_ruby won't spawn a new ruby interpreter.

https://github.com/shugo/mod_ruby

Answer (score 1):

Run this from your app root.

```
ruby -r webrick -e "s = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 8000, :DocumentRoot => Dir.pwd); trap('INT') { s.shutdown }; s.start"
```

Answer (score -3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby  //shebang line to indicate path to ruby.
require 'cgi'       //cgi file to create a simple cgi object.
cgi = CGI.new      //instantiating a cgi object. 
puts cgi.header   //thats telling the server about the type(html).
puts "hello"      // thats the output on the browser.
```